# How to retrieve value returned by page after state restoration

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

How can I get value returned by page after OS killed and restored app?

For example let's say I have app with two pages: home and color picker (sample code below).
Home page has button that pushes the color picker page and prints value returned by it.
Color picker has three buttons that pops with certain colors.

This solution works well until Android OS kills and restores app. Page stack is restored properly but color returned by color picker is no longer printed (which makes sense, since app was killed, anonymous function that awaits color from color picker is no longer working).

Navigator solved that problem using restorablePush method that return string that can be used in RestorableRouteFuture that can be restored allowing for retrieving value even after app was killed and restored.

The problem is that GoRouter doesn't have this functionality. Is there any solution or workaround to solve that issue?

sample code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({
    super.key,
  });

  final goRouter = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
            const MaterialPage<void>(child: HomePage()),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/color-picker',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
            const MaterialPage<Color>(child: ColorPicker()),
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Sandbox',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.orange),
      restorationScopeId: 'root',
      routerConfig: goRouter,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text('Pick color'),
          onPressed: () async {
            final color = await context.push<Color>('/color-picker');
            print('Picked color: $color');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorPicker extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColorPicker({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pick a color'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.pop(Colors.red),
              child: const Text('Red'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.pop(Colors.green),
              child: const Text('Green'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.pop(Colors.blue),
              child: const Text('Blue'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```